# Multiple tcp scanning tools integration

Tags: command-line, nmap, programming, scanner

I recently started my first programming project that consist of purpose multiple tcp scanning tools integration for multiple usage. To be more clear, I want to incorporate NMAP and MASSCAN tools. But, also, I want to know what is the more efficient:

Created `nmap` and `masscan` function with all the different scanning method in

```
nmap()

-stealth-scan
-agressive-scan 
...

masscan()

-stealth-scan 
-agressive-scan 
...
```

or create functions for all the different scanning method and, inside each one, ask which tool to use

```
stealth-scan()

-masscan? 
-nmap?

agressive-scan()

-masscan? 
-nmap?
```

I want to know what are best practices for multiple tools integration. If you have any advice or code to show me, you are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of relying on interactive input, I would try to implement arguments into your function. For example, -n for nmap, -m for masscan, -a for aggressive, -s for stealth etc.
You can then combine your arguments and won't have to rewrite your scripts when you want to add another tool to your integration.